# Vue JS - custom properties on vue component gives TS errors

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have created some Vue middleware and I am trying to add a custom property to one of my components in Vue like so:

**middleware.js:**

```
import { VueConstructor } from 'vue/types';
function eventPlugin(vue: VueConstructor): void {
  const Socket = new someClass();

  Object.defineProperties(vue.prototype, {
    $socket: {
      get: function get() {
        return Socket;
      },
    },
  });
  vue.$socket = Socket;
}
```

**myComponent.js**

```
const MyComponent = Vue.extend({
  name: 'MyComponent',
  $socket: {
    event(data: any) {

    }
  },
  methods: {
    MyMethod() {

    }
  }
})
```

**app.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import eventPlugin from './middleware.js';
import MyComponent from './myComponent.js'
Vue.use(eventPlugin);

export default new Vue({
  render: (h) => h(MyComponent),
}).$mount('#app');
```

The custom property I am trying to add here is obviously `socket`. The problem is when I add it I get typescript errors:

> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'socket' does
> not exist in type 'ComponentOptions<Vue, DefaultData,
> DefaultMethods, DefaultComputed, PropsDefinition<Record<string,
> any>>, Record<...>>'.

As you can see in `middleware.js` I have tried defining the property there so I am not sure why I am receiving the error?

Comment: The code you show creates `$socket`, not `sockets`.

Comment: And adding a property to the prototype wouldn't add it to the component options. It just let you access the property from the component context (e.g., `this.$socket` inside a method or hook).

Comment: Oh ok, is there a way to do it at all then?

Answer (score 0):

When adding instance properties or component options, you also need to [augment the existing type declarations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation).

Based on [*Augmenting Types for Use with Plugins* (Vue 2)](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Augmenting-Types-for-Use-with-Plugins):

- To type-hint the `$socket` instance property:

  ```js
  declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
    interface VueConstructor {
      $socket: string
    }
  }

  export {}
  ```
- To type-hint the `$socket` component option:

  ```js
  import Vue from 'vue'

  declare module 'vue/types/options' {
    interface ComponentOptions<V extends Vue> {
      $socket?: string
    }
  }

  export {}
  ```

The type declarations above should go in a `.d.ts` file in your `src` directory. If using VS Code, any new `.d.ts` files might require restarting VS Code to load.